# Time optimization when trying to apply order function in rows of a matrix

Tags: r, optimization

I am computing permutation patters on the rows of a matrix in `R` and I am using the function `order`. A permutation pattern assigns a number between 1 and the length of the vector, say `D`, to each number in the vector, being 1 assigned to the minimum, 2 for the next value greater than the minimum and so on. You can get an example using the function `rank` for any vector. I present my code below

```
A_pasted<-t(apply(A,1, order)) #apply order function to rows in the matrix
Z_concat<-apply(A_pasted, 1,paste0, collapse="_") #turn values into characters to make comparison
```

For example

```
 A =      
 [1,]   48    6   43   22
 [2,]   47   15   27   20
 [3,]   46   25   11   29
 [4,]   21   46   22   32
 [5,]   25   35   43   50
```

and

```
A_pasted=
[1,]    4    1    3    2
[2,]    4    1    3    2
[3,]    4    2    1    3
[4,]    1    4    2    3
[5,]    1    2    3    4

Z_concat
[1] "4_1_3_2" "4_1_3_2" "4_2_1_3" "1_4_2_3" "1_2_3_4"
```

where `A` is the matrix I want to operate. My main problem is that, although the first line of the code takes around 10 seconds per iteration, I have to replicate it hundreds of thousands of times, so I need a faster code that allows me to do the same. I've also tried using `parLapply` with rows previously converted to elements in a list, but it takes the same time.

Is there any other way to do this calculation?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `apply(A,1, order)` looks pretty suboptimal. We don't know what's in matrix A, please post its contents. Also please show `A_pasted`, why do you "turn values into characters to make comparison"? Which comparison?

Comment: The comparison I'm talking about is made among values of `Z_concat` and those obtained from all possible permutations, although it's not part of my question.

Comment: Please use `dput(A)` and `dput(A_pasted)` so your code sample is reproducible. Also, you mean it takes 10 seconds on all of A, or for each row? What are the dimensions of A?

Comment: I don't see why you need to represent each combination as a string `Z_concat` in order to make the comparison. Seems more efficient to represent the combination as a compound integer, e.g. `c(4,1,3,2) %*% (10^(3:0))` or `c(4,1,3,2) %*% (4^(3:0))`